How do I approach this volume problem?
I'm trying to find the volume of a body bounded by the surface given by the equation $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = (x^2 - y^2)z$, where $z \geqslant 0$. Here's my thought process: by observing that the we have mirror symmetry around $YZ$ and $XZ$ planes, we can only find only a quarter of the volume. Converting to spherical coordinates, we have that the surface has the equation $r = (\sin\theta)^2\cos(2\varphi)\cos\theta$. The volume can be found by evaluating the integral $\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_0^{(\sin\theta)^2\cos(2\varphi)\cos\theta}r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\varphi$, but this is where I ran into an issue - this integral is just equal to $0$. What am I doing wrong here? I looked at the graph of the surface and I know that the volume should be non-zero.

The solid consists of 4 identical "drops" connected in the origin $(0,0,0).$ Two of them lie above and two below the plane $xy.$ Intervals for the angles are not correct. As they are now, one half of a "positive"drop together with one half of a negative drop are considered. That's why they give 0.

The solid consists of 4 identical "drops" connected in the origin $(0,0,0).$
Two of them lie above and two below the plane $XY.$
The four pieces are separated by the planes $$x=y,x=-y$$ which can be deduced from the equation of the surface.
This determines the intervals for the angles. In particular, $\varphi$ in the "drop" lying above $XY-$plane, and with plane of symmetry $YZ,$ is such that $$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\varphi\leq\frac{3\pi}{4}.$$
I am sure you can finish now, as the rest of your computation is correct.

Ohh, I see. Thank you so much!

Now that I actually tried evaluating the integral again, I think we should consider $\varphi$ such that $-\frac{\pi}{4} \leqslant \varphi \leqslant \frac{\pi}{4}$, otherwise I get negative result. But yeah, I can see what I did wrong. Thanks again!
